# Monadic type confusion

Tags: haskell, types, monads, parsec

I am going through [Write Yourself a Scheme in Haskell](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours).  Its a great tutorial, but I've run into a wall with one of the [parsing exercises](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing):

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = liftM (Number . read) $ many1 digit
```

Rewrite parseNumber using:

1. Do-notation
2. explicit sequencing with the >>= operator

I had no problems with do-notation:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = do x <- many1 digit 
                 let y = read x
                 return $ Number y
```

For #2 I've tried a bunch of variations such as:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = (many1 digit) >>= (liftM (Number . read))
```

but I keep running into type errors.  I have two questions.

1. Why am I getting type errors? Am I misunderstanding the monadic bind operator?
2. Why AREN'T I getting similar type errors with my do-notation solution?

I feel like I am missing a fundamental concept regarding types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're attempting a non-trivial transformation from do-notation to bind notation, I recommend doing it the "trivial" way, and then making it points-free.

Recall:

```
 x <- m    === m >>= \x ->
 let x = e === let x = e in
```

Then you have:

```
 parseNumber = many1 digit >>= \x ->
               let y = read x in
               return (Number y)
```

(I've removed the `$` to avoid precedence problems.)

We can then convert this into:

```
 parseNumber = many1 digit >>= \x -> return (Number (read x))
             = many1 digit >>= return . Number . read
```

Now, if you want to use `liftM`, you need to stop using bind, since the lifted function expects a monadic value as its argument.

```
 parseNumber = liftM (Number . read) (many1 digit)
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, bind has type:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
```

(since you're using `Parser` as the Monad)

You give bind two arguments: the first one, `many1 digit`, should be ok (regarding the type); but the type of the second argument is the result type of `liftM`, namely `Parser a -> Parser b` and this does **not** fit the second argument's expected type `(a -> Parser b)`!

Without having tested it: instead of using `liftM (Number.read)` as second argument of bind, try using `return . Number . read` - this should have the right type and gives probably what you want...